# Ruby - extracting a substring from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array of strings in the form

```
["/currencies/avoncoin/"]
```

and i need to just get the name out (in this case, the string would be

```
avoncoin
```

How would I form a regular expression to do this with Ruby?

Comment: You could do this without: `File.basename "/currencies/avoncoin/"`. This would suggest that the string contains some kind of "path", similar to the pathes in a directory structure.

Comment: That's not a string, but an array containing a string. However, where does that string come from? Is it a filename, an URL path or something else? And how do you determine the substring's location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```
arr = ["/currencies/avoncoin/"]
arr = arr.map{ |s| s.gsub("/currencies/", "").gsub("/","") }
```

Comment: You can also do this with a one-shot regular expression if you use capturing brackets and `\1` in the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the one suggested by Shannon, you can also use the following approach.

```
arr = ["/currencies/avoncoin/"]
arr = arr.map{ |s| s.split("/").last }
```

This performs fewer operations and is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-scan) or its shorthand equivalent:

```
data.flat_map do |e|
  e.scan(%r[\A/currencies/([^/]+)/])[0]
end.compact
```

Here the `%r[...]` notation for regular expressions is used since your string contains `/` which is has significant meaning in the `/.../` default form. `flat_map` helps extract the matches, and `compact` strips out misses.

Operating on data like:

```
data = ["/currencies/avoncoin/", "/currencies/xcoin/", "/false/positive/"]
```

You'll get:

```
["avoncoin", "xcoin"]
```

Comment: Instead of `scan`, you could also use `map` and `e[%r[\A/currencies/([^/]+)/], 1]`

Answer (score 0):

If the match should be independent of the key, you can try

```
arr = ["/currencies/avoncoin/", "/currencies/xcoin/", "/something/else/"]    
re = /^\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\//

arr.map{ |str| re.match(str)[1] }
```

Or if using regex is not compulsory, you can do

```
arr.map{ |str| str.split('/').dig(2) }
```

which is more readable and rubyist.

The output for both will be `['avoncoin', 'xcoin', 'else']`

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
> s
=> "/currencies/avoncoin/"
```

You can do a regex slice in ruby:

```
> s[/([^\/]+)\/$/,1]
=> "avoncoin"
```